# chef cooking meals and how to go back n forth?

Tags: java

I'm practicing on making a cooking program and I'm stuck on the chefs cooking meals and also how to count how many meals both chefs have cooked.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cooking {

 int count = 0;
 String chefName;
 String foodName;   
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 public void chefName() {
    System.out.println("What is the name of chef 1?");
    scanner.next();
    System.out.println("What is the name of chef 2?");
    scanner.next();
    count++;
    //System.out.println("This week you made " + count + " deliveries!");
    //System.out.println("Bye, " + driverName + "!");
}

  public void foodName() {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Meal 1: What would you like to eat?");
    foodName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(chefName + " is cooking " + foodName);
    System.out.println("Meal 2: What would you like to eat?");
    foodName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(chefName + " is cooking " + foodName);
    scanner.next();
    count++;
  }
}

public class MainProgram1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create cooking records
    Cooking cookingByBob = new Cooking();
    cookingByBob.chefName = "Bob";

    Cooking cookingByAnne = new Cooking();
    cookingByAnne.chefName = "Anne";

    // Start delivering
    System.out.println("Hi!");
    cookingByBob.chefName();
    cookingByAnne.foodName();
```

When I run it Anne is the one cooking all the meals.

How do I make it so Anne cooks meal 1 then bob 2 and 3 and Anne 4 5? Also how do I count up all the meals both cooked?

Comment: In Your mainProgram1 class I could see you are calling food name method in cooking class only once with Anne object .

Comment: Also , If you could just frame your question properly ,on what is to be done and in what order do you want them printed , it would be helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you are getting a lot of abstractions wrong; and that makes it very hard for you to add the things to your code that you really need.

Example: classes should represent some "real" concept; something that resembles with reality. Your class `Cooking` isn't like that. It starts with the fact that this class queries the user for the name of the cook and the food; but on the other hand, your main program **programmatically** assigns values for those fields afterwards. That is just very confusing.

Just consider to change the whole thing like this:

```
class Cook {
   private final String name;
   Cook(String name) { this.name = name; }
```

allows you to create

```
Cook bob = new Cook("bob");
```

Then you could add methods to Cook like

```
class Cook { ...
   void prepareFood(String foodName) ...
   List<String> getPreparedFoods() ...
```

and now you can do

```
bob.prepareFood("1");
anne.prepareFood("2");
```

and later on

```
System.out.println("food by bob: " + bob.getPreparedFoods());
```

or something alike. The thing is: there is a lot of "noise" in your current program, and that makes it so hard for you to write down even that simple sequence in a correct way.

Long story short: before you start coding, think about the "things" and "behavior" that are required for the "story" you want to implement. Then build your program around those abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a working solution using the tools you are comfortable with, even though reading your code shows you are lacking the understanding of some basic java concepts. Do not just copy paste this, try to modify your own code. For a start, you could delete all the obsolete lines.

```
public class Kitchen {

    int count = 0;
    String firstChefName;
    String secondChefName;
    String foodName;    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setChefName() {
        System.out.println("What is the name of chef 1?");
        firstChefName = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("What is the name of chef 2?");
        secondChefName = scanner.next();
    }

    public void setFoodName() {
        System.out.println("Meal 1: What would you like to eat?");
        foodName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(firstChefName + " is cooking " + foodName);
        count++;

        System.out.println("Meal 2: What would you like to eat?");
        foodName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(secondChefName + " is cooking " + foodName);
        count++;

        System.out.println("Meal 3: What would you like to eat?");
        foodName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(secondChefName + " is cooking " + foodName);
        count++;

        System.out.println("Meal 4: What would you like to eat?");
        foodName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(firstChefName + " is cooking " + foodName);
        count++;

        System.out.println("Meal 5: What would you like to eat?");
        foodName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(firstChefName + " is cooking " + foodName);
        count++;
    }

}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create cooking records
    Kitchen kitchen = new Kitchen();

    // Start delivering
    System.out.println("Hi!");
    kitchen.setChefName();
    kitchen.setFoodName();
}
```

Comment: I haven't ran your code but wouldn't after `kitchen.setChefName();` it would just print our Meal 1: What would you...? with out pausing first to let the user type a response?

Comment: No, because as setChefName() gets called, each line of code in the method is executed before its setFoodName()'s turn. Scanner.next() is a so called blocking method, the user needs to enter something for the code to continue.

Comment: Try using the debugger, place a breakpoint at every crucial line and take a look at the order of execution. This should further help you to understand how Java works.